# how to get specific string from string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I've below string, I would like to get `2563` from the below string using shell script.

Could you please help, how to get the number which is after `request id`

```
"requested producer access with request id 2563 to product exampledomain.test-dev.test.nonprod.com for user : test-user on product test-product-validation-required"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `grep -oE '[0-9]*'` on string, like:

```sh
data="requested producer access with request id 2563 to product exampledomain.test-dev.test.nonprod.com for user : test-user on product test-product-validation-required"

echo $data | grep -oE '[0-9]*'
```

Output:
`2563`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string is stored in a  variable `$s`.

Is it the only number? Then

```sh
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <<< "$s"
```

would work.

Or using a Bash regex:

```sh
re='request id ([[:digit:]]+)'
[[ $s =~ $re ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id=$(awk -F" id | to " '{gsub(/ /,"", $2); print $2}' <<<$string)
```